# Laravel 4.2 - composer update issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I tried to run composer install and composer update as usual before working with a Laravel project. However I encountered a weird issue that I can't seem to solve for quite a while.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7:35
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7(35): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/Applications/X...', 35, Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(35): include('/Applications/X...')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/X...', Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(134): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/Applications/X...', Array)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7 on line 35
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7:35
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7(35): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/Applications/X...', 35, Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(35): include('/Applications/X...')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/X...', Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(134): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/Applications/X...', Array)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7 on line 35
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with me  
  ssage 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamp  
  pfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de  
  3dc7:35                                                                      
  Stack trace:                                                                 
  #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d  
  4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7(35): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleEr  
  ror(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/Applications/X...', 35, Array)                
  #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(35): include('/Applications  
  /X...')                                                                      
  #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\E  
  ngines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/X...', Array)                  
  #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(134): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEn  
  gine->get('/Applications/X...', Array)                                       
  #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles  
  /htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7 o  
  n line 35                                                                    
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid  
   argument supplied for foreach()' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/  
  wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7:35         
  Stack trace:                                                                 
  #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d  
  4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7(35): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleEr  
  ror(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/Applications/X...', 35, Array)                
  #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(35): include('/Applications  
  /X...')                                                                      
  #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\E  
  ngines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/X...', Array)                  
  #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wild-guanabana/vendor/laravel/fram  
  ework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(134): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEn  
  gine->get('/Applications/X...', Array)                                       
  #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles  
  /htdocs/wild-guanabana/app/storage/views/d4682a7a7da163c9444d69f6b6de3dc7 o  
  n line 35
```

After googling this issue, I tried the following solutions but none of them worked:

1. removing `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` and then running `composer install`
2. removing `bootstrap/compiled.php` and then running `composer update`
3. running `php artisan cache:clear` or `php artisan views:clear` to empty the `storage/views` directory. `php artisan` also does not work
4. I tried removing `storage/views` manually but it also failed
5. composer update --no-scripts.

I changed the folder's permission to `777` just in case it was a permission issue but it also failed.

Here's composer.json just in case:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

so I kept tracing the error I was getting from `storage/views` to find it in the first `foreach` loop:

```
<div class="sub-menu">
   @foreach($_destinationsList as $destination)
      <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="{{_url('destination/'.$destination->slug)}}">{{$destination->{_en('name')._ar('name_ar')}  }}</a>
        </li>
        @foreach($destination->children as $destination)
        <li>
         <a href="{{_url('destination/'.$destination->slug)}}">{{$destination->{_en('name')._ar('name_ar')}  }}</a>
        </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Adding to that I find the `url` function preceded by `_` which as far as I remember Laravel 4.2 was not there, you just write `url('url here')`. Also the `en` and `ar` follow the same issue. The first `foreach` loop keep stating `Invalid argument supplied for foreach`, which is weird since I can't use `php artisan` to migrate the database or even seed it.

What is more weird is that the same code is currently live and working normally.

Any idea what could be the issue here?!

Comment: Did you try manually deleting everything in app/storage/views ?

Comment: If you open a project in your IDE, do you happen to see something underlined like an error in the project folder stack?

Comment: @Norgul I am using brackets editor so there's no underlined error

Comment: Next time you run it, open the referenced file and track down the error. It's not liking something in your code. Fix that, and hopefully it should work.

Comment: @aynber could you be more specific?! The error appears to be in the storage/views folder which I normally do not alter so can I fix that?!

Comment: You don't want to fix it in the views folder, but rather in your blade template. If you look at that file in views, you can see where the error lies, fix it in your actual code (blade template), clear the views folder and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is weird, but I found the error. The `host` in the database configuration was set to `localhost` and for some unknown reason it was not working and giving the errors stated above. I changed it to `127.0.0.1` and it worked normally.

I can not figure out the real reason since there is nothing related to this part in the error trace.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the sudo composer install/update? I had similar issues today and fixed it with sudo

Comment: I always run the command using sudo so till now it is not working